# What is LLVM metadata

Tags: llvm

These might be very basic questions..

1) What is LLVM metadata and how do I use it in my program? I've read all the documentation, but I don't understand how to use it.

2) How to I add my personal metadata in a file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best source of information would be the blog post from 2010 that introduced metadata into LLVM IR - [Extensible Metadata in LLVM IR](http://blog.llvm.org/2010/04/extensible-metadata-in-llvm-ir.html). The first paragraph mentions the motivation:

> This metadata could be used to influence language-specific
>   optimization passes (for example, Type Based Alias Analysis in C), tag
>   information for a custom code generator, or pass through information
>   to link time optimization.

But reall, read all of if for the historical details.

The main "client" of metadata in LLVM is currently [debug info](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html). It's used by the front-end (e.g. Clang) to tag the LLVM IR it generates with debug information that correlates IR to the source code it came from. This same metadata is later translated to platform specific debug info such as DWARF by the code emitters.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have a small code that contains few conditional statements. How can I use GetMetadata() command to transfer custom metadata as the code traverses from one block to another?

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer: named metadata may be attached to instructions. You can extract it by calling the `Instruction::getMetadata` method, providing it the name of the specific metadata note you want to extract, for example `"dbg"`

Comment: Can you tell me how do I use this command in a simple Helloworld program?

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer: I don't understand the question. If you have new questions, feel free to post them separately, providing as much detail as you can on the problem you're working to solve.

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example of attaching Metadata to a program? Sorry for the vague question.

Comment: An up-to-date description of metadata in LLVM IR can be found in the language reference: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#metadata

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example:

```
  llvm::LLVMContext &Ctx = LLMod.getContext();
  llvm::IntegerType *Int32Ty = llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(Ctx);

  llvm::Metadata *MapleVerElts[] = {
    llvm::ConstantAsMetadata::get(llvm::ConstantInt::get(Int32Ty, 0)),
    llvm::ConstantAsMetadata::get(llvm::ConstantInt::get(Int32Ty, 1)),
  };

  llvm::NamedMDNode *MapleVerMD
      = LLMod.getOrInsertNamedMetadata("maple-as.version");
  MapleVerMD->addOperand(llvm::MDNode::get(Ctx, MapleVerElts));

  const MPLModule::FunctionListType &FuncList = Mod.getFunctionList();

  LLMod.dump();
```

And you may get the following output:

```
!maple-as.version = !{!0}

!0 = !{i32 0, i32 1}
```

Maybe it will give you a simple hint to use MetaData ^^