# How to convert LLVM IR br back to a while loop

Tags: javascript, c, llvm, emscripten

I am wondering how to do sort of transpilation of source to source using LLVM at a high level. Given that LLVM converts while loops to using `br` and the like, I am wondering how to then take that specific IR chunk and convert it *back* to a while loop in a language such as JavaScript.

```
C while loop -> LLVM IR -> JavaScript while loop
```

[This article](https://thenewstack.io/javascript-transpilers-need-know/) suggests that Emscripten converts LLVM code to JavaScript, so it probably handles this somewhere.

I'm wondering just the general strategy for converting it, if there is one. It seems a bit tricky from a distance, figuring out the statements to piece together a while loop from IR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the translation from C to LLVM IR, instructions that are deemed necessary can be decorated with Metadata, this metadata can then be used to convert LLVM IR to JavaScript, e.g indicating if the circular branching between basic blocks is a while loop or not (This information is present in the C context). See [Intrinsics & Metadata Attributes](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2016-11/Slides/Finkel-IntrinsicsMetadataAttributes.pdf).

For more information regarding LLVM Metadata see [LLVM-Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743861/what-is-llvm-metadata).

Answer (score 1):

In Emscripten the algorithm of recreating high-level language structures is called *Relooping* and is described [in this parer](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/docs/paper.pdf?raw=true). I'm not sure, though, that it is up-to-date information, but it probably answers your question.

Comment: Basically, they translate LLVM-IR to a low-level form of JavaScript without utilising Metadata if I understood the paper correctly?

Comment: Honestly speaking, I'm not sure I ever read that paper thoroughly. And if I even read, it was long ago. But as I remember, yes, they are detecting some basic patterns in LLVM IR. They could just emit every function as one big while & switch, but that would be not-so-optimizable for JS engines of that time (and, maybe, now as well) as far as I remember, so they implemented relooping.

Comment: And, yes, Emscripten usually emits special statically typed subset of JS -- Asm.js. It is even [standardized](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/). But now AFAIK they work on transition to WebAssembly.